# How to measure time in private network and to control mining process?

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, private-blockchain, javascript, timestamp

I am using private network with geth 1.7, and have some questions

1- To get the time of executing a function, i found some discussion about use of Data.getTime(), but i am wondering if anyone was successfully able to implement other methods such as performance.now() to measure time in geth commandlines? I tried but seems not defined function!!

2- how can i get the timestamp for a specific block if i knew the block number?

3- how can i mine only one block. For example, i send one transaction to the private network and then only mine one block containing that transaction. I found here some suggest to use while loop to check if there is no pending transactions and then stop mining. But i do not want this method, i would rather prefer to only mine one block.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1：You could  get the time of executing a function by updating source on jsre.go file,as follows:

```
func (self *JSRE) Evaluate(code string, w io.Writer) error {
    var fail error

    self.Do(func(vm *otto.Otto) {
        var startTime = time.Now();
        fmt.Println("jsre function ",code," start")
        val, err := vm.Run(code)
        if err != nil {
            prettyError(vm, err, w)
        } else {
            prettyPrint(vm, val, w)
        }
        fmt.Fprintln(w)
        fmt.Println("jsre function ",code," end ,consume time " ,(time.Now().UnixNano() - startTime.UnixNano()))
    })
    return fail
}
```

and then, deploy contract to test.

2: there is no way to obtain block timestamp by number, `block.timestamp` or `now` just is current block timestamp as seconds since unix epoch.

3:`miner.start(1);admin.sleepBlocks(1);miner.stop();` just mines one block and then will stop mine. Please notice executing by together.

Comment: Maybe difficulty too low generating two or three for point 3,this phenomenon require ayalysis source.
For point 1, you will update and compile source.
1. clone [go-ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum.git)
2. find method **Evaluate** in jsre.go file and replace **Evaluate** as follow:

Comment: func (self *JSRE) Evaluate(code string, w io.Writer) error {
 var fail error

 self.Do(func(vm *otto.Otto) {
  var startTime = time.Now();
  fmt.Println("jsre function ",code," start")
  val, err := vm.Run(code)
  if err != nil {
   prettyError(vm, err, w)
  } else {
   prettyPrint(vm, val, w)
  }
  fmt.Fprintln(w)
  fmt.Println("jsre function ",code," end ,consume time " ,(time.Now().UnixNano() - startTime.UnixNano()))
 })
 return fail
}

Comment: 3. cd go-ethereum dir on terminal and execute make all.
4. start geth.   './build/bin/geth --datadir=./dev/data --networkid 1 --dev console'   
      5. deploy your contract and test.

Comment: do the same but cannot get the time printed on the command line, how to print the time? Thanks

Comment: did you modify source and execute 'make all' to rebuild `geth`, and start geth by `./build/bin/geth --datadir=./dev/data --networkid 1 --dev console`? this way is ok for me, please every step is correct~

Comment: once i do make all get error; go-ethereum/cmd/evm/compiler.go:24:2: use of internal package not allowed
go-ethereum/cmd/geth/bugcmd.go:29:2: use of internal package not allowed
.. thanks